# Passenger server for Rails not picking up database change unless restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a small Rails app written in Rails3.1 and powered by passenger 3.0.12 on debian sqeeze. It has been running with no problem for a few years. Lately I noticed that sometimes when a user does a db operation (adding or removing a record), the display page doesn't pick up that change right away. Once I restart the passenger server (touch tmp/restart.txt), all changes are shown on the page. It happens from time to time since last week. The application has been in maintenance mode for a long time, mainly just bug fixing. What might be the possible cause for this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any caching turned on in Rails?  I think there is something a little funny with Passenger and memcache connections that could cause issues if you are caching.  http://russbrooks.com/2010/10/20/rails-cache-memcache-on-passenger-with-smart-spawning

Comment: What mr rogers said. Also, 3.0.12 is *very* old, over 2 years. You should upgrade to the latest version, 4.0.37, which not only fixes many bugs but is also a lot more powerful.

Comment: I do have this config.cache_classes = true. But those configuration hasn't been changed since it was deployed years ago. And the problem never showed up till now. passenger 3.0.12 was the latest one at the time the app was deployed. As I said it has been in maintenance mode for a long time. That's why it wasn't upgraded or anything. Maybe it's worthwhile doing so.